# Couldn't match expected type IO

Tags: haskell, tree

```
-- Binary Search tree

data Tree a = Empty 
    | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) 
     deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

leaf :: a -> Tree a
leaf x = Node x Empty Empty
insert :: (Ord a) => Tree a -> a -> Tree a
insert Empty x = leaf x
insert (Node x l r) y = case compare y x of
  GT -> Node x l (insert r y)
      _  -> Node x (insert l y) r
t1 :: Tree Int
t1 = Node 4 (leaf 3) (Node 7 (leaf 5) (leaf 10))

main = do
 insert t1 8
```

Error message:

```
{-

Couldn't match expected type `IO b0' with actual type `Tree a0'
    In the return type of a call of `insert'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: insert t1 8

-}
```

Comment: You should include more than your source code verbatim. PS: `main` must have type `IO ()`. Try `main = print (insert t1 8)`

Comment: `main` can have type `IO a`, for any `a` you like. It doesn't have to be `()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your** `main` function is of type `Tree Int` whereas compiled Haskell programs must have Type `IO a`.

You can convert your `Tree Int` value to `IO (Tree Int)` with [`return :: a -> IO a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v%3areturn) (signature simplified for your case):

```
main :: IO (Tree Int)
main = do
  return (insert t1 8)
```

However, this won't print anything to the console because it simply returns your tree as a value. To print the result you can use [`print :: Show a => a -> IO ()`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v%3aprint)

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  print (insert t1 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your insert function results in a type `Tree a` while main is typically a sequence of IO actions, type `IO a`.  Since `Tree /= IO` you have a slight problem.  Perhaps you would like to print the tree, `main = print (insert t1 8)`.